# How to GET from API synchronously in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, promise, fetch-api

**TLDR: How to use ES6 fetch to download *synchronously*?**

I'm trying to write a script in Node to download data from an API till there is no more to download e.g. the endpoint has a dataset of size roughly 12000 but only provides 100 per call, and I need all the data. So I've decided to have it downloaded synchronously, and only stop when the json returned is finally empty.

```
// function to make one api GET call
getData = (offset) => {
  return fetch('http://...'+'?start=' + offset)
    .then(...)
}

// make api calls until json is finally empty, 
// indicating that I've downloaded all the data
offset = 0
const results = getData(offset)
while (results.length != 0) {
  // combine results...
  i += 100 // move offset
  results = getData(i)
}
```

Because I don't know precisely how large the data is and at which offset it ends, whether or not to make another call depends on the last one.

The code above fails because the promise from `getData()` does not resolve in time for the while loop. In another language, this would be okay as getData blocks until it is completed. I've tried to `await` `getData` but it needs to be in an `async` (which I don't know where to place, I already have promises). Is there any way to force `getData()` to block until it is resolved?

Comment: async function returns promises as well. so you can call getData from another async function and can use await inside this function

Comment: Is that you whole script? If yes, put the "main" code block inside an `async function main() { … }` and call that with `main().catch(console.error)`. (Or make it an `async` IIFE)

Answer (score 0):

you can mark your getData() function as `async`

```
async getData() {
  return fetch('http://...'+'?start=' + offset)
    .then(...)
}
```

then `await` for the returned promise completion

```
await const results = getData(offset)
```

Or you can modify your code to handle the logic of whether to make another call in the promise callbacks. Something like

```
function fetchData(offset) {
  if (offset < 1000) {
    return Promise.resolve([1,2,3].map(i=>offset+i));
  } else {
    return Promise.resolve([]);
  }
}

function needsMoreData(results) {
  return results.length > 0;
}

function fetchNextDataIfNeeded(results, offset) {
  if (needsMoreData(results)) {
    return fetchRemainingData(offset + 100)
     .then(nextResults=>[...results, ...nextResults]);
  }
  return Promise.resolve(results);
}

function fetchRemainingData( offset) {
  return fetchData(offset)
      .then(results=>fetchNextDataIfNeeded(results, offset));
}


function fetchAllData() {
  return fetchRemainingData(0)
   .then(results=>console.log(results));
}

fetchAllData();
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/rwycbn5q/1/

Answer (score 0):

I recently found myself in a similar situation, but some functions cannot be made synchronously. But you could do something like this:

```
let results=[];

getData(idx)=>{
  fetch("url").then(data=>{
    if(data!=={}){ //Or some other continuation check
      results.push(data); //Or whatever you want to do with the data
      getData(idx+100);
    }
  })
}

getData(0);
```